# For discrete points, is there anything similar to the effect of gradients?

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

Suppose I have k points (2 dimensions), $(m_{1x}, m_{1y}), (m_{2x}, m_{2y}), ..., (m_{kx}, m_{ky} ) $. I want to get the next direction to make the current path the shortest, that is, $min \sum_{i=0}^{k+1} |m_{i}m_{i+1}|$ (|ab| is the length of the line segment) .

I have tried the forward difference, but this is just a number with no direction. Although I can search a small scale first to get directions (greedy ideas), it is inefficient.

Can someone help or provide something useful? thanks : )

Comment: This is a variant on the travelling salesman. I suggest you look in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

[Added]

It sounds to me from your description that, given you are at a point $(m_x, m_y)$, after travelling some path to get there, you are searching for the closest unvisited point to $(m_x, m_y)$, so as to minimize the total length of the *trip up to this point*. If so, this is different, and simpler, than the travelling salesman problem, which seeks to minimize the total length of the entire trip. If the shortest total trip is your actual goal, note that this process of minimizing the initial stages is a poor strategy, highly unlikely to give you the shortest total trip.

But if "shortest extension of current trip" is your goal, then the strategy below is much more efficient for large numbers of points that searching all the points for the next one to visit.

The idea is to organize the points by their coordinates. Then it searches for a square around the current point that is sure to contain the nearest point. Distance are only compared for points in this square.

To find the square, it searches points with nearby $x$-coordinates to $m_x$ until it finds one whose $y$-coordinate differs from $m_y$ by at most as much as the $x$-coordinate differs from $m_x$. This point lies in a square of half-side length $s = |x-m_x|$. The farthest any point within the square can be from $(m_x, m_y)$ is $\sqrt 2s$. So we enlarge the square to have half-side length $\sqrt 2s$, so every point within $\sqrt 2s$ of $(m_x, m_y)$ is in the larger square. Since there is at least one point no further away than this, the closest point has to be in this square. So the algorithm only compares distances within the square to find that closest point. But I suggest choosing a square slightly larger than $\sqrt 2s$ to ensure that computation error doesn't miss some points close to boundary.

---

[Original Post]

One possible approach is to sort the points first by $x$ coordinate, then by $y$ coordinate.
If you are at a point $m = (m_x, m_y)$ and want to find the next point, you check the points in the list with the nearest $x$ coordinate to $m_x$. For each of these, check the nearest $y$ coordinate to $m_y$. If for that point $|y-m_y| > |x - m_x|$, expand your search to the second nearest $x$ to $m_x$, and so on, until you find a point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $|y_0-m_y| \le |x_0 - m_x|$.

Once you've found that point, choose a convenient $k > \sqrt 2|x_0-m_x|$ (for example, $k = 1.415\times |x_0 - m_x|$) and search all points with $|x - m_x| < k, |y - m_y| < k$. For these, calculate $(x-m_x)^2 + (y - m_y)^2$ and choose the point with the lowest value. Remove that point from the list (or mark it as used, and never include it in future searches).

Once you find that $(x,y)$, the direction you want go is that of $$(x-m_x, y-m_y)$$

Comment: This method is confusing, can it really replace the gradient direction? Can you give some explanation?

I drew a [picute](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/filess/img19@main/2021/12/07/1638844096584-24df36dd-d0e5-4fe5-9430-b7fb360b0e83.png) according to your idea

Search for the nearest point ($min \space |x-m_x|$) in the range of $|slope| \leq 1$ => Let $k = c*|x-m_x|\space (c\geq\sqrt2)$ => Search for the point with the smallest Euclidean distance in the box => Sub 2 points as gradient replacement

Comment: Yes, it really narrows the seach space effectively, I will try it, thanks : )

Comment: I added the explanation of how this algorithm works to the post itself, and deleted my comments, which unfortunately had a condescending feel to them that I had not intended.